# protractor calling an exported function within the same module

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, protractor

I'm newer to using Protractor for automation, so forgive me if this ends up being a dumb question. I have a `helper.js` module with a bunch of functions that I or other team members can use. One of the functions from `helper.js` needs to call to one of the existing functions in the module.

Is this possible? I have tried several different ways to do this and so far none have worked other than to break the helper functions into a separate js file that I need to call to.

Example:
helper.js:

```
module.exports = {
    newbrowsertab: function(){
        <code>
    },
    anotherfunction: function(){
        <code>
        <call to newbrowsertab();>
        <code>
     },
     anotherfunction2: function(){
         <code>
     }
};
```

In the call to the newbrowsertab function, I've tried:

- `module.newbrowsertab();`
- `this.newbrowsertab();`
- `self.newbrowsertab();`

Comment: How are you calling anotherfunction?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Prototypal inheritance then:

```
// helper.js functions

// create object
var Util = function() {};

// extend object
Util.prototype.enterPassword = function() {
    // code
};

// extend object
Util.prototype.clickLogin = function() {
    // code
};

// use `this` to call functions in same module
Util.prototype.fullLogin = function() { // extend object
    this.enterPassword();
    this.clickLogin();
};

module.exports = new Util();
```

Then in your test file:

```
var Util = require('./path/to/helper.js);

Util.fullLogin();
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the prototypal convention.

Any functions that are only helpers for other exported functions could be named with an underscore and declared to be executed later.

```
function _helperFunction(){
  // do something
  // return something
}
var exposedFunction = function() {
  // do something
  var x = _helperFunction();
  // Do something else
}


module.exports = {
  exposedFunction : exposedFunction
};
```