# Protractor: Unable to call exported function within the same module

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have written a export module using protractor. it has multiple function defined inside it.
Now, I want to call one of the exported function inside another function within the same module.
My module looks like below.

```
module.exports = {
    read_page_number_data: function {
        // code here
    },
    read_page_data: function {
        this.read_page_number_data().then(function () {
            // Code here.
        });
    },
    check_link_present: function {
        // code here
    },
    click_link: function {
        this.check_link_present().then(function () {
            // Code here.
        });
    },
}
```

Now, when I call read_page_data function in my test script, I get below error.

**Failed: this.read_page_number_data is not a function.**

I have tried all the options given in below question. still there is no success.

[protractor calling an exported function within the same module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440899/protractor-calling-an-exported-function-within-the-same-module)

**NOTE: Before calling *read_page_data* function, I am calling *click_link* function, which internally calls *check_link_present* function. But this call works fine and *check_link_present* function gets call properly from *click_link* function. After this, control navigates to the page given in link.**

Comment: you should prefix 'this.' to all method 'read_page_number_data' in export module. It should be like 'this.read_page_number_data'

Comment: Thanks @SureshSalloju for the reply. But, when I prefix "this." in all the functions, I get below error


[21:33:56] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:34:01] E/launcher - Error: C:\uiauto\lib\search_lib.js:4
        this.enter_search_key_home_page: function (key) {
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: can you try like my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to assign the object to a variable specific to your module.
e.g.

```
module.exports = myModule = {
    //...
}
```

Then you can call your functions within the module with `myModule.read_page_number_data()` etc.

You can find an example [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kohlikohl/05k9qcdk/1/).

**Note on `this` context**

One thing to keep in mind is that `this` can change it's context depending on how the parent function is called, which could be why it is working for `click_link` but not for `read_page_data`.

You can find more information on the `this` keyword [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Thanks Matthias.. This solutions seems to be working for me. Now function is getting called from other function.

Comment: Awesome! Please consider accepting it as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't try like below. This is one of the best practices for Page Object Model test framework.

```
var PageName = function(){
              this.firstMethod = function(){
                //logic
              };
              this.secodnMethod = function(){
                //logic
              };
  }

module.exports = new PageName();
```

Comment: Even I had tried with this way. Still the same problem arises. And I get the same old error.

Comment: in which file your accessing and how r u accessing ?

Comment: Thanks Suresh. Below solution worked for me. Actually I have defined a page library module. And then these function are getting called from the test script. But one specific function inside the page module requires to call the other function inside same module... That's where it was failing.